# Store data in cloud

Tags: windows-8, cloud, data-storage, onedrive

I am New at Windows 8 app development. I want to create an app which stores data in skydrive like this

```
<person>
     <name>XYZ</name>
     <geb>01.01.1992</geb>
     …
</person>
```

How can I do this? I only find a version to send a value with an array index. How can I save data as XML or whole files like xml or pictures in the cloud?

Comment: skydrive allow only you to upload binary files. You can also use Azure mobile service for cloud database

Comment: Can I use Azure cloud database for commercial useage? And is it free or do I have to pay for this? An other point is if my app is used by 10000 people (i don't think that it would be so populare) is the data save from other users and what about the general performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Azure mobile service to store data in cloud as tables. It is paid service and you can use it for commercial purpose. Here's some posts which might be helpful to you.

[Announcing Windows Azure Mobile Services](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/08/28/announcing-windows-azure-mobile-services.aspx)

[Windows Azure Mobile Services - Channel 9 Series](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services)

[Windows Azure Mobile Services - MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj554228.aspx)

[Windows Azure Mobile Services - MSDN Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=Technology&f%5B0%5D.Value=Windows%20Azure%20Mobile%20Services&f%5B0%5D.Text=Windows%20Azure%20Mobile%20Services)

[Windows Azure Mobile Services - Official Site](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/)

Comment: is it possible to connect to the SQL Database over the Mobile Service so I can store my data in a real SQL Database and not only in this little tables? And how can I be save the all useres only have rights to see their own data and not the data from an other user?

Comment: do you want to connect SQL server to Azure mobile service ?

Comment: Right I want to send data from my app over a mobile service to a SQL database.

Comment: SQL server and SQL Azure both things are different, you can't connect as per my knowledge. Simple meaning of SQL Azure is "SQL server" on cloud. Why do you want to connect SQL server to Azure mobile service ? Try to find on [Windows Azure Mobile Service Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/azuremobile/threads)

Comment: I only want to save data from the user. For example the user has some students from different classes who writes notes in different subjects - I think a SQL database is the best storage for this. How can I easily store this data from my windows 8 app using azure? What do you think is the best way for this?

Comment: Azure is the best way to save data on cloud as relational SQL database. The links which I have given in answer is enough to perform that. I would be happy if you mark it as answer and upvote it.